# prolog in math - searching the level of node in prolog

Tags: math, prolog, logic, prolog-toplevel

Assuming here is a binary search tree, and given the rule that  `above(X,Y)` - `X` is directly above `Y`. Also I created the rule `root(X)` - `X` has no parent.

Then, I was trying to figure out what the depth of node in this tree.
Assume the root node of tree is "r" So I got fact `level(r,0)`. In order to implement the rule `level(N,D) :-`, what I was thinking is it should be have a recursion here.
Thus, I tried

```
level(N,D): \+ root(N), above(X,N), D is D+1, level(X,D).
```

So if `N` is not a root, there has a node `X` above `N` and level `D` plus one, then recursion. But when I tested this, it just works for the root condition. When I created more facts, such as node "s" is leftchild of node "r", My query is level(s,D). It returns me "no". I traced the query, it shows me

```
  1    1  Call: level(s,_16) ? 
  1    1  Fail: level(s,_16) ?
```

I just confusing why it fails when I call  `level(s,D)`?

Comment: Did you forgot a dash (`-`) in your query, or is this just a typo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some problems with your query:

- In Prolog you cannot write something like `D is D+1`, because a variable can only be assigned *one* value;
- at the moment you call `D is D+1`, `D` is not yet instantiated, so it will probably cause an error; and
- You never state (at least not in the visible code) that the `level/2` of the root is `0`.

A solution is to first state that the level of any root is `0`:

```
level(N,0) :-
    root(N).
```

Now we have to define the inductive case: first we indeed look for a parent using the `above/2` predicate. Performing a check that `N` is no `root/1` is not necessary strictly speaking, because it would conflict with the fact that there is an `above/2`. Next we determine the level of that parent `LP` and finally we calculate the level of our node by stating that `L is LP+1` where `L` is the level of `N` and `LP` the level op `P`:

```
level(N,L) :-
    above(P,N),
    level(P,LP),
    L is LP+1.
```

Or putting it all together:

```
level(N,0) :-
    root(N).
level(N,L) :-
    above(P,N),
    level(P,LP),
    L is LP+1.
```

Since you did not provide a sample tree, I have no means to test whether this predicate behaves as you expect it to.

---

**About `root/1`**

Note that by writing `root/1`, you introduce data duplication: you can simply write:

```
root(R) :-
    \+ above(_,R).
```

Comment: Yes! level(N,D) :- above(X,N), depth(X,O), D is O+1. is what I did later. But I lost the base case. I followed by the recursion. So above is my general case and the base case really annoyed me cause I tried "level(N,D) :- root(N), D is 0." "level(N,0)." and they does not work. The base case is necessary. I was thought I should represent all of variables that provided in "()" after":-".

Comment: The first one should work `level(N,D) :- root(N),D is 0.` The second means every `N` has level `0` (thus all nodes of the tree).